# проблема с функцией var for if else +

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookie, геолокация, перевод

помогите разобраться с обновления скрипта нужную!
вот скрипт который определяет страну и язык пользователя,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        ymaps.ready(function()
        {
            var country = ymaps.geolocation.country;


            $('#country').html(''+country);

            (function(){var a=document.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.id="aze_eng";a.async=!1;a.src="/translate_Azerbaijan.js";var b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b);})();

        });
    });
</script>
```

у меня есть скрипт переводчик на три языке 
вот они

```
/translate_Azerbaijan.js
/translate_English.js
/translate_Russian.js
```

теперь тут надо настроит так чтоб при входе на сайт из Англии 
в этом строке `a.src="/translate_Azerbaijan.js";`

слово **/translate_Azerbaijan.js** менялся на на **/translate_English.js**

имя страны определяется с помощью этого кода `$('#country').html(''+country);` 
это кот `+country` выводит имя страну ,
надо так сделать чтоб получилось как то так `a.src="/translate_+country.js";`
если возможно напишите пожалуйста готовый скрипт, а то я не очень в скриптах, по этому обращаю вам,

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение которое видимо вам подойдет:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0-stable/?load=package.standard&lang=ru-RU"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script id='lang' src='test.js'></script>
<!-- Для вывода страны -->
<div id="country"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        ymaps.ready(function() {
            var country = ymaps.geolocation.country;
            $('#country').html('Ваша страна ' + country);
            var ele = document.getElementById('lang');
            switch (country) {
            case 'Россия':
                ele.src = '/translate_Russian.js';
                break;
            case 'Азербайджан':
                ele.src = '/translate_Azerbaijan.js';
                break;
            default:
                ele.src = '/translate_English.js';
                break;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Но хочу обратить внимание что используя такие костыли для локализации Вы возможно приобретете больше проблем...Одну из которых вам стоит учесть сразу замена(подмена) файла еще не вызовет его инициализацию т.е она с точки зрения документа будет уже пройдена решения этих вопросов так же есть но это то-же костыли...Забегая вперед Вам потребуеться еще одна функция которая будет пробегаться по документу и вставлять значения из объекта локализации по ключу в объекта документа...Обратите внимание на сторонние библиотеки локализации.

UPD Скрипт поправил

Comment: а вы проверяли это скрипт чтоб он работает или нет, ваш скрипт не работает, и еще это не подходит. лучший бы сделать по короче, здесь **+contry** нам выводится называние страны, теперь надо так сделать чтоб c помощью функции **var ,for, in ** сделать так чтоб , **+contry** стоял вот так translate_**+contry**.js

Comment: Скрипт адаптирован...Синтаксис скрипта направлен на доходчивое объяснение его функционала и Вашем праве изменить его на свой лад...

Comment: И еще раз отмечу такой момент что библиотека Яндекса возвращает название страны на русском языке: `http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0-stable/?load=package.standard&lang=ru-RU `

Comment: если  **ru-RU** менять на **en-Ru** тогда Яндекс возвращает называние на Английском

Comment: Да именно так )

Comment: что именно так, если называние будет на Английском тогда какая проблема? вот решил с помощью  этого [сайта](http://likbezz.ru/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=1807&p=5036#p5036)

Comment: вот скрипт готовый `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        ymaps.ready(function(){
          var country = ymaps.geolocation.country;
               
               var a=document.createElement("script");
               a.type="text/javascript";
               a.id=""+country+"";
               a.async=!1;
               a.src="../translates/translate_"+country+".js";
               var b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
               b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b);
         
          $('#country').html(''+country);
        });
    });
</script>`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36946/discussion-between-samir-mamedov-and-peter-slusar).